# lamp-server package versus installing individual components

Tags: lamp

Is it better to install a LAMP platform on Linux (Ubuntu) using

`sudo aptitude install lamp-server`

or by installing each individual component separately?

Why or why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such package on Ubuntu.

However if there was one like this, I think it would be a metapackage, that is a package that does not contain stuff by itself, but just depends on other packages (apache, mysql and php in this case).

If that was the case there would not be a difference.
Except maybe that via the metapackage you might install stuff you don't need, so if you know exactly what you need you'd better just install it and go.

What is disrecommended is installing things like XAMPP on Linux. They are not integrated with the system as well as the original packages, and you would not get security upgrades automatically.

Answer (score 1):

the command is

```
sudo apt-get install Lamp-server^
```

i think the best way is to use the tasksel command

you can install that with the command

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel

sudo tasksel
```

select lamp server and install it.

there are 53 components that install on a lamp server so its best to install the package

after installing the LAMP server you need to install the the phpmyadmin client

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

last step is retart apache

```
sudo etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to install the highest level package possible.  This ensures you get all the components you need.  On upgrades you will get any new packages which have been added, and packages which are no longer required get removed.  You will end up installing all the components anyway, but it will take more effort.

The debian package manager has been designed to ensure you get all the dependecies intalled.  It will install any missing packages, and use already installed packages.  There can be alternatives, and you get a default package installed.  This can be changed by either pre-installing another alternative, or installing it later.

To install lamp server, you may need to install mysql-server, but this does not need to be on the same server as apache.  Otherwise you will want mysql-client.  This is a deployment decision you need to make.  Installing php5 will pull in apach2 as a depndency.   Any LAMP based packages such as wordpress will bring in the components which need to be installed on the server.

Answer (score -1):

What does it matter?  Just get the software on the server you need to do the work you want to accomplish.

After the initial installation I do not know of a package that will pull all that in.

But again, simply install the components you need to accomplish your task.

And honestly, I would prefer installing individual packages rather than metapackages, especially for something so nebulous as a "LAMP" server, where the value P is ambiguous.

Everything you install becomes a vector for problems, minimize that where possible.